# jQuery onClick once with on/off switch

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to figure out how to do something but can not figure out the correct terminology to do so.

What I am trying to do is have a textbox (#price) that when clicked once it will open up a pdf calculator that will then either prefill the textbox when completed or will then allow the user to enter the amount in. But I also want this to work if the textbox is "tabbed" over to also instead of the onClick. (Maybe onBlur) Basically anytime that textbox is used I need it to work like that. But how do I make the onClick know when the amount is ok to be entered or if the calculator needs to open?

What also makes this tricky is I need to have an On/Off switch basically a checkbox that when checked it allows that pop up pdf calculator and when its not checked it just ignores it and allows the price to be entered still.

Does anyone have any suggestions or pointers in how I can achieve this goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 1. A textbox (#price) that when click once it will open up a pdf calculator

Use jQuery's `click()` handler or `bind("click", ...)`

```
var $price = $("#price");
$price.click(function() {
    $("#pdf_calculator").fadeIn();
});
```

#### 2. But I also want this to work if the textbox is "tabbed" over to also

Use the `focus` event to know when an input is active (i.e, has been "tabbed" to). Alternatively, the `blur` event can be used if you want to know when a user is "leaving" the input field. *('blur' is the opposite of 'focus')*

```
$price.on("focus click", function() {
    $("#pdf_calculator").fadeIn();
});
```

#### 3. But how do I make the onClick know when the amount is ok to be entered or if the calculator needs to open?

Grab the amount typed in by the user, convert it to a numerical value, then perform your validation steps.

```
$price.on("focus click", function() {
    // Do some validation checking on the amount entered.
    var enteredValue = parseFloat($price.val());
    if (!isNaN(enteredValue) && enteredValue > 0) {
        $("#pdf_calculator").fadeIn();
    }
});
```

#### 4. What also makes this tricky is I need to have an On/Off switch basically a checkbox that when checked it allows that pop up pdf calculator and when its not checked it just ignores it and allows the price to be entered still.

Simply check that the checkbox is checked using jQuery's `is(":checked")` then combine the steps above, and your fully working code looks like this:

```
var $price = $("#price");

$price.on("focus click blur", function() {

    // your checkbox element
    var checkbox = $("#show_calculator");

    // Check if the checkbox is checked
    if (checkbox.is(":checked")) {

        // convert the entered string to a number
        // then validate it according to your needs
        var enteredValue = parseFloat($price.val());
        if (!isNaN(enteredValue) && enteredValue > 0) {

            // if all conditions are met, 
            // show the pdf calculator
            $("#pdf_calculator").fadeIn();
        }
    }
});
```

[Click here to review a **working jsfiddle** of these ideas.](http://jsfiddle.net/s70r2qkp/)

**As for the pdf form** (and getting values in and out again of a pdf form) there isn't a straight-forward method that doesn't involve a 'hack' (that may or may not work across different browsers). If the pdf only has ONE input, then you can capture the keyboard events on your form popup, and send them back to the HTML form (which is an ugly hack), but if this were my project, I would just convert the pdf functionality to javascript, and then you have all the freedom you need, and your calculator is 100% compatible with the rest of your application.

**Hope this helps!**

Comment: What about correcting the tab issue? If you check the checkbox and then tab to price it does not pop up. It will still allow them to enter an amount before using the calculator. They will only know to use the calculator if they click in the box. Sometimes some users just fly through the forms without clicking at all. Is there a way to correct that issue as well as have it happen when clicked in?

Comment: @ZaneZ, well, the 'focus' event does handle the "tab" issue, where the `on("focus")` does get called when the price field is tabbed over to, but the validation rules are currently keeping the form from popping up (because right now it says that the entered value needs to be a number, and greater than zero), if you were to take the validation out, then the pdf div would pop up just fine. Try it for yourself by typing in a number greater than 0, then checking the checkbox, and tabbing over to the price field. The pop will pop up in those circumstances.

Comment: You had asked about how to do validation (see #3 in my answer), so that is why the validation is there. Another way of testing to get the "tab" feature working, is to change this line in my fiddle: `if( !isNaN(enteredValue) && enteredValue > 0 ) {` to this: `if( true ) {`, then you will see how the price field can be "tabbed" over to

Comment: Ultimately, it is up to you to determine what validation rules fit your application, the ones I entered were just for demonstration purposes.

Comment: To see the minimum amount of code you need to get just the "tab" feature working, you can review this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y6fvjota/

Answer (score 1):

Bind event handler to `focus` event (`blur` is for when control looses focus).

```
$("#price").on({
 "focus": eventHandler
})
```

Then in your `eventHandler()` check if calculator needs to be invoked, by checking if it's already opened: `$("#calculatorDiv").is(":visible")`, and checking if your checkbox is 'checked': `$("#checkboxId").is(':checked')`, and depending on that open it.

Comment: Wouldn't this cause the event handler to be triggered twice when the textbox is clicked? Focus covers both events, he doesn't need a click event.

Comment: @Lopsided yep you are right, in most cases focus will be invoked on click as well, I'll update answer

Answer (score 1):

The event(s) you are looking for is onFocus and onBlur. I would bind a function to the onFocus event that first checks if the corresponding checkbox has a "true" (or "checked") value, then continue if it does and do nothin if it doesn't.

I'd create an example in jsfiddle for you if I wasn't answering this from my phone.